# Cloud Foundry - Installing Micro Bosh in a VM ( OpenStack )

Tags: openstack, cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I have followed the instructions on http://cloudfoundry.github.com/docs/running/deploying-cf/openstack/install_microbosh_openstack.html to install the micro bosh in a VM.

I'm a little confused about the micro_bosh.yml:

```
name: microbosh-openstack

env:
 bosh:
    password: $6$u/dxDdk4Z4Q3$MRHBPQRsU83i18FRB6CdLX0KdZtT2ZZV7BLXLFwa5tyVZbWp72v2wp.ytmY3KyBZzmdkPgx9D3j3oHaDZxe6F.


 level: DEBUG

network:
 name: default
 type: dynamic
 label: private
 ip: 192.168.22.34


resources:
 persistent_disk: 4096
 cloud_properties:
    instance_type: m1.small

cloud:
  plugin: openstack
  properties:
   openstack:
       auth_url: http://10.0.0.2:5000/v2.0/tokens
       username: admin
       api_key: f00bar
       tenant: admin
       default_key_name: admin-keypair
       default_security_groups: ["default"]
       private_key: /root/.ssh/admin-keypair.pem
```

what is the api_key used for? I don't comprehend the meaning of this key. 
And the default key name?

Can someone please explain this configuration options better?

thanks

Bruno

**EDIT**

the answer to this question can be found here:
https://github.com/drnic/bosh-getting-started/blob/master/create-a-bosh/creating-a-micro-bosh-from-stemcell-openstack.md

Answer (score 1):

```
http://10.0.0.2:5000/v2.0/tokens
```

Likely refers to the Keystone Service API.

This API authenticates you to OpenStack's keystone identity service.  All REST API Services are catalogued there in the catalog service.  Additionally all of OpenStack relies on keystone to authenticate all API queries.

Knowing nothing about bosh the attribute 'api_key' to me requires better context.

Generally OpenStack doesn't require an API Key in its own concept of API authentication.

More about openstack api authentication here:

http://docs.openstack.org/api/quick-start/content/index.html#Getting-Credentials-a00665

However there is a concept of an API Key in relation to EC2 keys.  These can be generated with this query:

```
keystone ec2-credentials-create
```

My guess is that's what it requires there.

More alternatives there:

Credentials could be in in novarc file generated for your Openstack project with nova-manage project zipfile command. This is also available from the horizon interface.

Alternatively it could refer to a provider specific API Key such as rackspaces ( I doubt this ):

http://docs.rackspace.com/servers/api/v2/cs-devguide/content/curl_auth.html

'default_key_name' probably refers to the name of a keypair that has been previously registered with openstack.  This would be a keypair that can be injected into an image at instance run time.  It should correspond to the .pem filename.  The key would need to be available to your user and your tenant that  you choose in the config.

Check out a keypair creation / use example here:

http://docs.openstack.org/developer/nova/runnova/managing.instances.html

Best effort man.  Hope that gives you what you need.

Comment: I found the answer in another question here in Stack OverFlow, the api-key is just a lame name for the password :D, you'are right about the keypair. Thanks for the help anyway :)